# Gradle - extract file from depended jar

Tags: zip, extract, distribution, gradle

I want to extract file "default.jasperreports.properties" from depended jasperreports.jar
and put it in zip distribution with new name "jasperreports.properties"

Sample gradle build:

```c
apply plugin: 'java'

task zip(type: Zip) {
    from 'src/dist'
  //  from configurations.runtime
    from extractFileFromJar("default.jasperreports.properties");
    rename 'default.jasperreports.properties', 'jasperreports.properties'

}

def extractFileFromJar(String fileName) {
    //    configurations.runtime.files.each { file -> println file} //it's not work 
    // not finished part of build file
    FileTree tree = zipTree('someFile.zip')
    FileTree filtered = tree.matching {
        include fileName
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    runtime 'jasperreports:jasperreports:2.0.5'
}
```

How to get FileTree in extractFileFromJar() from dependency jasperreports-2.0.5.jar?

In script above I use

```c
FileTree tree = zipTree('someFile.zip')
```

but want to use somethink like (wrong, but human readable)

```c
FileTree tree = configurations.runtime.filter("jasperreports").singleFile.zipTree
```

---

PS: Try to call

```c
def extractFileFromJar(String fileName) {
    configurations.runtime.files.each { file -> println file} //it's not work 
...
```

but it doesn't work with exception

> You can't change a configuration which is not in unresolved state!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (sometimes code says more than a thousand words):

```
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    jasper
}

dependencies {
    jasper('jasperreports:jasperreports:2.0.5') { 
        transitive = false
    }
}

task zip(type: Zip) {
    from 'src/dist'
    // note that zipTree call is wrapped in closure so that configuration
    // is only resolved at execution time
    from({ zipTree(configurations.jasper.singleFile) }) {
        include 'default.jasperreports.properties'
        rename 'default.jasperreports.properties', 'jasperreports.properties'
    }
}
```

Comment: A litle note about usage 

        transitive = false

It's not work on my custom maven repositories hosted on googlecode.com
My actual script is 
http://oracle-ddl2svn.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.x-gradle/build.gradle?r=202
when I add 

    dependencies {
     distributive 'com.googlecode:scheme2ddl:2.0' {
        transitive = false
     }
    }
I got error 
> Could not find method com.googlecode:scheme2ddl:2.0() for arguments [build_2tnud3244b5lndbqkchi9t13at$_run_closure3_closure6@e38fca] on root project 'oracle-ddl2svn-gradle'.

Comment: Thanks again :) I'm newbie in gradle yet

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
configurations {
    batch
}

dependencies {
    batch 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:3.0.8.RELEASE' { 
        transitive = false
    }
}

def extractBatchSql(path) {
    def zipFile = configurations.batch.find { it =~ /spring-batch-core/ }
    def zip = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(zipFile)
    def entry = zip.getEntry(path)
    return zip.getInputStream(entry).text
}

task tmp() {
    dependsOn configurations.batch

    doLast {
        def delSql = extractBatchSql("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql")
        println delSql
    }
}
```