# Additional gradle configuration breaking compilation when using flatDir repo

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using the approach from [Gradle - extract file from depended jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339237/gradle-extract-file-from-depended-jar) to extact a .so file from inside a native JAR.

```
configurations {
    special
}

dependencies {
    special('org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-linux-i586')
}

task extract(type: Copy) {
    from({ zipTree(configurations.special.singleFile) })
    include 'natives/linux-i586/*.so'
    into "$buildDir/extracted"
}
```

This works fine, however it appears to break compilation of code that depends on `org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2`, the non-native Java part.

```
TestJogl.java:1: error: package com.jogamp.opengl does not exist
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL;
```

The compilation fails if the project is built with `clean extract build` but not `clean build`

I've simplified the code to

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL;

public class TestJogl {
    private GL gl;
}
```

and corresponding build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    compile "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2"
}
```

I've isolated this issue to the usage of "`flatDir`" repo. The exact same project compiles fine when using `mavenCentral()`. Note using a legacy corporate network without artifactory or direct Internet access.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
           dirs "$rootProject.projectDir/local-repo"
           // contains jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-i586.jar
           //          jogl-all-2.3.2.jar
        }
    }
}
```

I've managed to work around the issue by changing the dependency to explicity specify `@jar`, which should be implicit

```
compile "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2@jar"
```

The same problem occurs in both single and multi project layouts.

My analysis: This is a bug in Gradle. Somehow when using flatDir Gradle gets confused and thinks that the dependency has been setup, but uses the native JAR instead of the Java JAR.

Questions: Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Is there another way to workaround it?

Environment: Gradle 3.5, JDK 1.8u144