# Load messages files in MessageSouce from imported jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I have spring boot application using i18n that imports a jar file as a library.
In jar library there are messages.properties files `messages.properties, messages_en.properties, ...` that I want to use.

Problem is that `messages.properties` files from the library are not loaded and I can't use translations from them.

I have MessageSource bean set up as bellow and I can't figure out what path should I add to access `messages.properties` files in the library. Now only messages.properties files from the main app are used

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource  messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames(
                "classpath:messages", 
//              " path to messages in library ?" 
        );
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Messages in the library were added to resources, so they are in the base folder of the jar
[image: library_structure_picture]

Comment: is it working now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution. I have changed name of messages in one project so they were not the same as names in the other. F.eg.: messages.properties, messages_en.properties in one project and messages2.properties, messages2_en.properties in second project (library).

Than i've added path to messages and messages2 in configuration as bellow and all messages were accessible.

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages", "classpath:messages2");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

It comes out that messages files names can't be the same

Answer (score 1):

Use Claspath in messageSource

```
"classpath:/ResourceBundle/messages"
```

hope it will work for you

**for external jar**

please try to extract *.properties file from jar into resources folder using maven plugin in pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-jar-file</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>groupID</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                                    <version>version</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                                    <includes>**/*.properties</includes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build
```

Comment: It does not work. Resource Bundle is not a folder. It is made by Intellij to group messages but there is no physical folder

Comment: could you please let me know folder structure inside jar where messages properties file persist

Comment: When you open jar file there are: META-INF, pl, messages.properties, messages_en.properties, messages_pl.properties files as You can see in the picture in question

Comment: still it is not clear to me. please let me know in which folder messsages files are present inside jar.

Comment: it will search in classpath for messages file
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", java.util.Locale.getDefault());

please try this, hope it will work for you

Comment: messages files are on the same level as META-INF and pl folders. ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", java.util.Locale.getDefault()); unfortunately returns only messages that are in main app, but not messages that are in library :/ messages are not seen as files in resources

Comment: Please check I have edit the previous solution for jar, hope it will help you

Comment: Sorry for no response i was on a break. I will check this in my spare-time. I am using gradle, so i have to see how to do this with it.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339237/gradle-extract-file-from-depended-jar